# Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to design this very simple application where you input 2 numbers and the app will calculate the smaller common multiple for all numbers between the 2 input numbers.

The function itself works well (judging from the result from console); however when I try to link to HTML with event listeners, glitches happen. Thus I'm assuming I'm making some mistakes when linking to HTML.

With some numbers my app works fine, but with some numbers, for some reason, it doesn't work (for instance, inputs 2 and 10, 7 and 11....etc.). The error says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
```

Here's my code.

```js
const smallNum = document.querySelector('#smallernum')
const bigNum = document.querySelector('#biggernum')
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const result = document.querySelector('#result')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  result.value = smallestCommons([smallNum.value, bigNum.value])
})


function smallestCommons(arr) {
  arr.sort((a,b) => a-b)

  let lowerNum = arr[0]
  let higherNum = arr[1]
  let newArr = []
  let primeOfArr = []
  let shortDivisionArr = [];

  // Create an array of nums inbetween the two extreme nums
  for(let i = lowerNum; i <= higherNum; i++) {
    newArr.push(i)
  }

  // Create an array of primes up until largest num
  for(let i = 1; i <= higherNum; i++) {
    let flag = 0;
    for(let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
      if(i % j === 0) {
        flag = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(i > 1 && flag === 0) {
      primeOfArr.push(i)
    }
  }

  // Short Division
  for(let i = 0; i < primeOfArr.length; i++) {
    while(newArr.some((num) => num % primeOfArr[i] === 0)) {
      for(let j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++) {
        if(newArr[j] % primeOfArr[i] === 0) {
        newArr[j] = newArr[j] / primeOfArr[i]
        }
      } shortDivisionArr.push(primeOfArr[i])
    }
  }
  return shortDivisionArr.reduce((a,b) => a*b);
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div id="main">
      <div class="title">
        <h2>This App Helps You Find The Smallest Common Multiple Of Consecutive Numbers Between 2 Nums!</h3>
        <p>2 nums inclusive. App for demonstration purpose. Please don't use this to cheat on your homework!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="calcs">
        <div class="inputnums">
          <input id="smallernum" type="text" placeholder="Enter a smaller num">
          <input id="biggernum" type="text" placeholder="Enter a bigger num">
        </div>  
        <button>Click to calculate!</button>
        <input id="result" type="text" placeholder="Result is here!">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Please just post your code inside the question. You can include the necessary code, which is likely an excerpt of your HTML and some JavaScript.

Comment: Please realize that the input numbers are strings. You're getting the error because when you do `arr.reduce((a, b) => a*b)`; `reduce` expects a second argument as the *initial value*, i.e. what value to start off from. When you supply an array of numbers `reduce` automatically sets the initial value to 0, but when you come up with `NaN` and other kablooshskusk.

Comment: @code "*reduce expects a second argument as the initial value, i.e. what value to start off from.*" only if the array has a single element. The second argument is optional otherwise. Although you'd want to use it if your accumulator/result and input are of different types. "*When you supply an array of numbers reduce automatically sets the initial value to 0,*" no, it does not. If the initial value is skipped, then the first element of the array is used as initial value. It will never be set to zero or anything else static based on the type of the data.

Comment: @code I agree with VLAZ regarding reduce. But thanks for pointing out my blind spot - didn't realize at all that the values passed into the function are string. Fixed by adding parseInt and now it's working

Comment: @VLAZ yes, that's right. I got it confused with some other thing; I wanted to point out that the input was a string and got on a rabbit trail ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
The values passed into the function (smallNum.value and bigNum.value) are strings.
Transformed them into integers using parseInt() and it's working now.